# How to validate decimal stepping from a starting number in PHP

Tags: php, rounding

I need to validate that an inputted number is a valid number based on my stepping rules and round up to the nearest valid number if not. These numbers will change but one example would be:

```
$min = 0.25;
$step = 0.1
$qty = 0.75  // user input
```

so these would be valid inputs:
0.75
0.85
0.95

But these should round:
0.76 (to 0.85)
0.80 (to 0.85)

I thought I could use modulus somehow but not getting the calculation correct.

```
if (($qty % min) / $step == 0)) {
    echo "good";
}
```

I've tried some variations of math that are likely very wrong

```
$step = 0.1;
$min = 0.25;
$qty = .85;

$h = ($qty / $min) / $step;
echo $h;

$j = mround($qty, $min-$step);

echo $j;


function mround($num, $parts) {
    if ($parts <= 0) { $parts = 1; }
    $res = $num * (1/$parts);
    $res = round($res);
    return $res /(1/$parts);
}
```

Comment: So the steps start at the minimum and not at zero? What to do with values below the minimum? I should also ask what you have tried, and what you have problems with...

Comment: if the value is less than the minimum, it will just use the minimum
I've updated the question with what I've tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `fmod` to do this.

```
$new = $original + ($step - fmod($original - $minimum, $step));
```

[Example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/W4JGr)

Comment: Thank you! I would have never figured that out